# Tag disambiguation VCL (apache/varnish-vcl versus delphi/visual component library aka VCL)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Most of the questions tagged VCL are about the Delphi Visual Component Library, VCL, but at least 10% of the VCL tagged questions are for the Varnish Configuration Language (also VCL).

Can the tag synonym system in StackOverflow be set up to retag [varnish](/questions/tagged/varnish) + [vcl](/questions/tagged/vcl) to [varnish](/questions/tagged/varnish) + [varnish-vcl](/questions/tagged/varnish-vcl), to avoid VCL tags on Varnish showing up in Delphi [vcl](/questions/tagged/vcl)?  If not, then can the 90% of the [vcl](/questions/tagged/vcl)'s that are also tagged [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) be  auto-retagged [delphi-vcl](/questions/tagged/delphi-vcl)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the SO tag synonym system isn't smart enough to look at tag combos when suggesting synonyms.

There are only five [varnish](/questions/tagged/varnish) + [vcl](/questions/tagged/vcl)s.  I've gone ahead and retagged them to [varnish-vcl](/questions/tagged/varnish-vcl).  There are probably a few other Varnish-related ones lurking.